# Overcoming the 23 point restriction on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-directions-api

I am looking for a way to overcome the 23 point restriction to address a larger (1000) number of points for a larger number of vehicles(10).

As a result a type of genetic algorithm implementation should be followed for this process to be achieved.

Anybody who has documentation or solution on that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is looking to circumvent the restrictions placed on the usage of the API and would directly violate the Terms of Use.

Comment: I'm not looking to circumvent any restriction because it's not possible to do it.

What I'm asking is if anybody is familiar with any techniques that use the 23 point limitation (maybe through multiple requests - this is allowed) to achieve an optimum route solution for more points.

Comment: I'm not looking to circumvent because it's not possible to do it.

What I'm asking is if anybody is familiar with any techniques that use the 23 point limitation (maybe through multiple requests - this is allowed) to achieve an optimum route solution for more points.